# VBScript not doing what's needed

Tags: object, vbscript

```
Dim checkon, check
checkon = 1
toggle = 0
Do While checkon = 1
    If (Chr(window.event.keyode = "m")) and toggle = 0 Then
        toggle = 1
        MsgBox "working"
    End If
    If (Chr(window.event.keyode = "m")) and toggle = 1 Then
        toggle = 0
    End If
    Do While toggle = 1
        If window.event.button = 1 Then
            MsgBox "working"
            WshShell.Sendkeys ("-{F10}")
            WScript.Sleep 500
        End If
    Loop
Loop
```

The goal of this is to have it be run, and constantly check for the user to press <kbd>M</kbd>, which alternated `toggle` between 0 and 1. When `toggle` is true, the program is supposed to check for the mouse being held down and if it is click twice a second.

Currently it's giving an error

> Object required:'Window"

and before that it did simply nothing. I am aware the code looks ugly, but I pasted msgboxes as a method of debugging what's going wrong, and none of them activated.

Comment: `keyode`? how about `keyCode`

Comment: `Chr(window.event.keyode = "m")` probably should be `Chr(window.event.keyode) = "m")`

Comment: How are you running this?  In a browser, or thru WScript or CScript?

Comment: VBScript can't monitor keyboard or mouse button events.

Comment: To Chris, I am running this as a file with a .vbs extension and double clicking on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you can't listen to events like that in a VBScript CScript environment. Usually `window.event` would imply the presence of a web page, but you said you're running this from the desktop, so perhaps you copied the code from a bad example. You may need to use another language or tool to do this.